# Java Wildcard Separator

Tags: java, pattern-matching

I have recently been working on Wildcard Pattern Matching where the format is:

```
"http(yyy|xxx|zzz|fssadasd|asdasd|asdasdas|asdasdasd|://)www.w3schools(.com|.org|.net).*"
```

for the data:

http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_default

I have developed a pattern matching function to execute when the format is single bracketed(multiple or operators). How do i get to store all possible combinations of the above mentioned format(multiple brackets and multiple operators).

Some of the Possible combinations:

httpyyyw3schools.com.*

httpxxxw3schools.com.*

httpzzzw3schools.com.*

httpyyyw3schools.net.*

httpxxxw3schools.net.*

httpzzzw3schools.net.* etc.,

Please do let me know if the question is still unclear?

The Pattern Matching Function is:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
public class wildcardtest
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {

    test("h*p(://|xxx)ww*", "http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_default"); 
    test("h*p(yyy|://)ww*", "http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_default"); 
    test("h*p(yyy|xxx|zzz|fssadasd|asdasd|asdasdas|asdasdasd|://)ww*", "http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_default"); 
    test("ge?ks*", "geeksforgeeks");
    test("g*k", "gee");
    test("*pqrs", "pqrst");
    test("abc*bcd", "abcdhghgbcd");
    test("abc*c?d", "abcd");
    test("*c*d", "abcd");
    test("*?c*d", "abcd");
    test("*", "abcd");
    test("?", "a");
    }

    static boolean matches(String format, String data) {

        if(format.contains("|"))
        {

            int openpos = format.indexOf("(");
            int closepos = format.indexOf(")");

            String match = "";
            Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\((.*?)\\)");
            Matcher m = p.matcher(format);

                while(m.find()) 
                {
                    match = m.group(1);
                }

            String after = format.substring(closepos+1);
            String[] spliiter = match.split(Pattern.quote("|"));

            for(int i = 0;i<spliiter.length;i++)
            {
                 StringBuilder before = new StringBuilder(format.substring(0,openpos));
                 before.append(spliiter[i]).append(after);      

                 if (matches(before.toString(),data)) {
                    return true;
                 }

            }           
            return false;
        }



    if (format.length() == 0 && data.length() == 0)
        return true;

    if (format.length() == 1 && format.charAt(0) == '*')
        return true;

    if (format.length() == 0 && data.length() > 0)
        return false;

    if (format.charAt(0) == '*' && format.charAt(1) != 0 && data.length() == 0)
        return false;

    if (format.charAt(0) == '?' || format.charAt(0) == data.charAt(0))
        return matches(format.substring(1), data.substring(1));

    if (format.charAt(0) == '*')
        return matches(format.substring(1), data) || matches(format, data.substring(1));

    return false;
}

    static void test(String first, String second)
    { 
        System.out.println(matches(first, second)); 
    }

}
```

Comment: What do you mean by *How do i get to store*? Also, if `www.` is optional, use `(?:www\.)?` Generally speaking, to match a literal `.` you need to use `\.` in the pattern. In terms of performance, `(.com|.org|.net)` loses to `(\.(?:com|org|net))`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew i need to store those combinations in a list so that i can pass it to my wildcard pattern matching function and the format given above is just an example test case.The main aim is to accept multiple bracketed inputs containing multiple OR conditions.

Comment: Then please show your code.

Comment: ya sure ill post the code

Comment: I have included the code in my question ...Please go through it

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of any library method that will do this.

Consider the general problem:

> Write a function to list all possible strings that will match a given regex.

If the regex contains a `*`, the result of that will be an infinite set of strings.  (Or if we restrict ourselves to Java `String` object, the set will be finite, but impossibly large to represent.)

If we restrict function to only cover the alternations then we get a finite set of possible strings.  However:

- that functionality is not *generally useful* and (AFAIK) nobody has thought to implement it as a library method
- unless your regex language excludes `*`, the test cases you generate may not adequately cover the functionality you are trying to test.

But could you implement it?

Well yes, you could.  But you would need to write a parser to parse the input regexes in order to do this.  My gut feeling is that you would spend a lot of time coding up and testing that parser.  More time than it would take to write test cases with hand written / hardwired sets of string matching each example regex.